# Selection in Flex Datagrid does not pass the valueObject to selectionChangeHandler function

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, datagrid, value-objects

I have a TabNavigator, and each tab is a Module. One of the modules is labelled Units and the full code of the module is posted in this post.

There are several problems:
1) Forms are not populated with data from the datagrid selection.
2) Selecting a row and clicking delete gives the very-common error: `TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.` 
A trace on the valueObject unit within the selectionChangeHandler function gives NULL. Why?

Note: In other modules (other tabs of the TabNavigator), I have DropDownLists populated with units. This means that the valueObject Unit is defined in the other modules. However, valueObjects should be private to modules, and not shared. I am unsure where the problem comes.

Full module code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Module xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
          xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
          xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
          xmlns:unitservice="services.unitservice.*"
          xmlns:valueObjects="valueObjects.*"
          width="724"
          height="674">
    <fx:Style source="assets/CAaNDFlex.css"/>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;

            import spark.events.GridSelectionEvent;

            protected function unitsDg_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                getUnitsResult.token=unitservice.getUnits();
            }

            protected function addBtn_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                currentState="unitsAdd";
                unit=new Unit();
            }

            protected function unitsDg_selectionChangeHandler(event:GridSelectionEvent):void
            {
                trace(event.currentTarget.selectedItem); //Unit object detected
                trace(event.currentTarget.selectedItem as Unit); //NULL 
                trace(unit); // unit is NULL. Why?
                currentState="unitsDetails";
            }


            protected function button_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                trace(unit); // unit is NULL. Why?
                unit.unitName=unitNameTextInput.text;
                if (unit.unitID == 0)
                {
                    createUnitResult.token=unitservice.createUnit(unit);
                }
                else
                {
                    updateUnitResult.token=unitservice.updateUnit(unit);
                }
            }

            protected function updateBtn_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                currentState="unitsUpdate";
            }

            protected function createUnitResult_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
            {
                currentState="unitsDetails";
                unit.unitID=event.result as int;
                unitsDg.dataProvider.addItem(unit);
                unitsDg.setSelectedIndex(unitsDg.dataProvider.getItemIndex(unit));
                unitsDg.ensureCellIsVisible(unitsDg.selectedIndex);
            }

            protected function deleteBtn_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                deleteUnitResult.token = unitservice.deleteUnit(unit.unitID);

            }

            protected function deleteUnitResult_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
            {
                unitsDg.dataProvider.removeItemAt(unitsDg.selectedIndex);
                currentState="units";
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:states>
        <s:State name="units"/>
        <s:State name="unitsDetails"/>
        <s:State name="unitsAdd"/>
        <s:State name="unitsUpdate"/>
    </s:states>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:CallResponder id="getUnitsResult"
                         result="unit = getUnitsResult.lastResult as Unit"/>
        <unitservice:UnitService id="unitservice"
                                           fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString + '\n' + event.fault.faultDetail)"
                                           showBusyCursor="true"/>
        <valueObjects:Unit id="unit" />
        <s:CallResponder id="createUnitResult"
                         result="createUnitResult_resultHandler(event)"/>
        <s:CallResponder id="updateUnitResult"/>
        <s:CallResponder id="deleteUnitResult" result="deleteUnitResult_resultHandler(event)"/>



        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Binding destination="unit" source="unitsDg.selectedItem as Unit"/>

    <s:DataGrid id="unitsDg" x="10" y="37"
                creationComplete="unitsDg_creationCompleteHandler(event)" requestedRowCount="4"
                selectionChange="unitsDg_selectionChangeHandler(event)">
        <s:columns>
            <s:ArrayList>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="unitName"
                              headerText="unitName">
                </s:GridColumn>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="unitID"
                              headerText="unitID">
                </s:GridColumn>
            </s:ArrayList>
        </s:columns>
        <s:typicalItem>
            <fx:Object unitID="unitID1"
                       unitName="unitName1">
            </fx:Object>
        </s:typicalItem>
        <s:AsyncListView list="{getUnitsResult.lastResult}"/>
    </s:DataGrid>
    <s:Button id="addBtn" x="10" y="0" label="Add" click="addBtn_clickHandler(event)"
              styleName="actionButton"/>
    <s:Form includeIn="unitsAdd,unitsUpdate"
            x="10"
            y="176"
            defaultButton="{button}">
        <s:FormItem label="unitName">
            <s:TextInput id="unitNameTextInput"
                         text="{unit.unitName}"/>
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:Button id="button"
                  label="Add"
                  click="button_clickHandler(event)"
                  label.unitsUpdate="Update"/>
    </s:Form>
    <s:Button id="updateBtn" x="138" y="0" label="Update" click="updateBtn_clickHandler(event)"/>
    <s:Button id="deleteBtn" x="266" y="0" label="Delete" click="deleteBtn_clickHandler(event)"/>
    <s:Form includeIn="unitsDetails" x="10" y="176">
        <s:FormItem label="unitName">
            <s:Label id="unitNameLabel" text="{unit.unitName}"/>
        </s:FormItem>
    </s:Form>
</s:Module>
```

Comment: If you're getting this "common" error `Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference`, ever thought that maybe you aren't null checking enough or aren't casting your objects properly?

Answer (score 2):

The selectedObject is not successfully casting to Unit, which means it probably wasn't Unit or a subclass prior to the cast.  Casting it to Unit won't make it a Unit unless it was one before.

Comment: You are totally right. A temporary solution was to change the Binding to:
`<fx:Binding destination="unit.unitID" source="unitsDg.selectedItem.unitID"/>
 <fx:Binding destination="unit.unitName" source="unitsDg.selectedItem.unitName"/>`

Comment: It is to be noted that, if I disable all the other tabs (i.e I do not load the other modules), the posted module code works all fine. That said, if the unit valueObject is used somewhere else, the casting fails. Very very weird.

Comment: What's happening there is that your Unit code is only referenced inside your modules, and so whichever loads first "gets" the definition for Unit, and the others have a "sort of" definition for Unit.  In order to make this work correctly, use Unit in your shell or make sure that all of your Modules are loading into the parent ApplicationDomain.

Comment: ^ you do that by setting the "currentDomain" property of the module to `ApplicationDomain.currentDomain`.